# Manipulating Ruby class default values

Tags: ruby, arguments, dice

When there is more than one default value, how could I change only the second initialization variable without also calling the first?

For example, a Ruby class is created to return the value akin to the roll of a single die with default values for a six sided die ranging from 1 to 6:

```
class Die

  def initialize(min=1, max=6)
    @min       = min
    @max       = max
  end

  def roll
    rand(@min..@max)
  end
end
```

If I wanted instead to use this code to simulate the return from rolling a 20 sided die, I could write the following:

`p Die.new(min=1, max=20).roll`

...but is there a way to argue only the second (max) value?

Of note - and this is where I am confused (I don't fully understand Ruby class attributes and variable scopes) - if I invoke:

`p Die.new(max=20).roll`

... I get `nil` printed. ?. (I understand that this is because `rand(20..6)` returns `nil`, but I thought that `max=` would retain the default min value for the first argument - instead `max=20` gets ingested as the integer `20` binding to the `min=`... This seems weird to me.)

I suppose I could re-work the Die class to take a default value of the number of sides and also set the min (or max) value relative to the number of sides, but this is beside the point of my main question: How to override only the second default value without explicitly writing the first as well...

Presuming that most dice would normally have a minimum value of 1, I realize that I could reverse the order of min and max like so:

```
class Die2

  def initialize(max=6, min=1)
    @max       = max
    @min       = min
  end

  def roll
    rand(@min..@max)
  end  
end
```

...and then invoke whatever maximum number of sides like so:

```
p Die2.new(20).roll
```

...but given the syntax of `class Die` (and my inclination to write the minimum before the maximum) is there a way to only enter an argument for the second value? Or, perhaps I am approaching Ruby classes poorly? Any help or guidance is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write

```
class Die
  def initialize(min=1, max=6)
    @min, @max = min, max
  end
end
```

and create a new instance by passing a single argument, such as:

```
die = Die.new(3)
  #=> #<Die:0x007fcc6902a700 @min=3, @max=6>
```

we can see from the return value that the argument `3` has been assigned to `@min` and `@max` gets its default value. In short, to pass a value to `@max` you must also pass one to `@min` (unless, of course, you reverse the order of the arguments).

You can do what you want by using *named arguments* (or *named parameters*), introduced in Ruby v2.0.

```
class Die
  def initialize(min: 1, max: 6)
    @min, @max = min, max
  end
end

die = Die.new(max: 3)
  #=> #<Die:0x007fcc698ccc00 @min=1, @max=3>
```

(or `die = Die.new(:max=>3`). As you see, `@min` equals its default value and `@max` equals the argument that is passed, `3`.

Default values were required for keyword arguments in Ruby v2.0, but v2.1 extended their functionality to permit required named arguments as well. See, for example, [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments).

Lastly, consider the following two cases (the second being the more interesting).

```
class Die
  def initialize(min=1, max: 6)
    @min, @max = min, max
  end
end
die = Die.new(max: 3)
  #=> #<Die:0x007fcc69954448 @min=1, @max=3>

class Die
  def initialize(min, max: 6)
    @min, @max = min, max
  end
end
die = Die.new(max: 3)
  #=> #<Die:0x007fa01b900930 @min={:max=>3}, @max=6>
```

Comment: Mr. K, no, that was a relic that I've now removed. Initially, I planned to retrieve the values of the instance variables (`die.min` and `die.max`)--hence the need for `attr_reader`--but then it occurred to me that the return value for `new` would provide that information,  but I forget to remove `attr_reader`.

Comment: Ah, yes - that does help me tho! (...maybe not directly pertinent to the question but I am new to ruby and programming and now I see better what's going on there w/attr_reader/writer/accessor, so thanks for explaining!) :)

Comment: The min/max model here might be misleading labels. You probably want `sides` and `base`, like how some dice go 0..9 and others are 1..10. There's also those that are 00, 10, 20...

Comment: @tadman Good point - sides/base makes a lot of sense for building a more robust dice class. Would the range then be `rand(@base..(@base + (@sides - 1))`?

Comment: Mr. K, should that not be `rand(@base..@base+@sides)`? Alternatively, `@base + rand(sides)`.

Comment: @tadman, good suggestion, but I did not change my answer because the question seems to be a general one about the values of method arguments that have default values.

Comment: Cary, wouldn't it be triple dots: `rand(@base...@base+@sides)` to exclude the last integer (presuming we are advancing one integer at a time and not skipping any), e.g. a base 10 die with 6 sides would cover 10,11,12,13,14 & 15, but the `..` syntax would include (base 10 + sides 6 = 16), no?

Comment: Again, you're right. I personally always use two dots, so it would be as you had it before. (I find three dots easy to miss.) My alternative suggestion is still OK.

Comment: Mr. Swoveland, likewise, I've been testing them out too :) and yes, the alternative you proposed reads the nicest, imho. When I first thought about the suggestion by @tadman I was thinking there was an "n -1" in there somewhere... but I am not all that advanced with mathematics. Prolly getting a little off topic at this point (and a little ahead of what I am trying to accomplish) but I am interested to work out solutions for dice which advance other than by single integers... Thank you, I really appreciate your help and insights!

Comment: There are also non-numeric dice or dice whose numbers are not consecutive. For a robust class, you should just pass the sides explicitly (e.g. `Die.new(*1..6)`) and call `sides.sample`. If you use certain dice often, consider using a subclass, i.e. `class SixSidedDie < Die`.

Comment: @Stefan `sides.sample` would be randomly sampling from a "sides" array, yes? I have much to learn... Also, I don't know how to read the * in the `Die.new(*1..6)` - is this like a wildcard character?

Comment: @Stefan - ah-ha, the "[splat](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-labs/labs/ruby-pearls-vol-1-the-splat)"

Comment: @CarySwoveland years of pen-and-paper role-playing games ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy it's a shorthand notation for `Die.new(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`. And yes, [`Array#sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-sample) returns a random element from an array.

Comment: Mr. K, note that the main form of [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) takes an argument `n` that defaults to `1` and returns a sample of size `n` from the array where sampling is done *without replacement*. By contrast, using `rand` `n` times to obtain a sample of size `n` constitutes *sampling with replacement*. A sample size of `1` does not call for that distinction, of course.

Comment: @Stefan, don't you mean  "roll-playing games"?

Comment: @Stefan & Mr. Swoveland, when the computer opponent in the yahtzee game I am working towards becomes the most popular ever because of it's lean coding, difficulty to beat and efficient scaling, I will have this link at the ready to credit my mentors :D Srsly - thank you both for your insights. exactly how to use the unary "splat" operator and the sampling from an array (vs. rand) for a more robust Die super class is a wee bit over my head right now, but the overview is invaluable to me - much obliged!

Comment: @Stefan & Mr. Swoveland - [can we continue this in a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125981/discussion-with-stefan-and-cary)?

Comment: Mr. K. Please see chat.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 2.0 and higher you can use keyword arguments to achieve the same effect:

```
class Die

  def initialize(min: 1, max: 6)   #<--declare arguments like this
    @min       = min
    @max       = max
  end

  def roll
    rand(@min..@max)
  end
end

p Die.new(max: 20).roll            #<--and call like this
```

https://repl.it/Dyxn/0

you can read more about keyword arguments in this [article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments)